# Springboot @Scheduled Pauses

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I've written a springboot application to perform etl from data source to another data lake every 15 mins. I've scheduled the execution using `@Scheduled` annotation to a function.

I had created `jar` and was executing directly through `java -jar ingest.jar`. It works fine for some days (3-4 days). And just pauses without any exception. To resume, I have to go and press any key to make it active again.

```
@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${ingest.initialdelay.in.seconds}000", fixedRateString = "${ingest.rate.in.seconds}000")
public void ingestData(){
    // Ingestion Logic
}
```

Because the problem persisted, I created `war` and deployed to the tomcat server. But the problem still remains.

Can somebody point me what am I missing here? The same application works fine if I deploy to cloudfoundry.

IO Streams - `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`

**Helper Functions for IO**

```
public static void saveLastSuccessfulDate(String filepath, String propertyName, Date dateTime) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        String lastDate = getDateInFormat(dateTime);
        log.info("Saving: " + lastDate);

        output = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

        prop.setProperty(propertyName, lastDate);

        prop.store(output, null);

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


//Helper to Write to properties file
public static String checkLastSuccessfulDateAsString(String filepath, String propName) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream(filepath);

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

        String lastSuccesfulDate = prop.getProperty(propName);

        log.info("Last Successful Date: "+lastSuccesfulDate);
        return lastSuccesfulDate;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
        log.error("checkLastSuccessfulDateAsString: File Not Found: " + f.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

Regards

Comment: It sounds like your ETL logic is going into an infinite loop after some amount of time. Spring can't schedule the next run if the thread is tied up. You can probably debug this by lowering the rate to once per second (or something similarly fast).

Comment: Don't you think, If that is the case, a "key press" wouldn't resume execution?

Comment: True, but waiting for input is an infinite wait loop until a value appears on the input stream.

Comment: IO Streams I've used - RDBMS, Read/Write Properties from Properties Files. I am reading using helper function at many places. And writing using helper function at one place. Added Helper Functions

Answer (score 0):

In default, spring @Scheduled use single thread. So, if one task was blocking, the next task won't run.

You can make your task class implements SchedulingConfigurer.It will use multithread to run task and avoid blocking. Code like it:

```
@Component
public class TaskService implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public ScheduledExecutorService taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }

    // your code
    @Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${ingest.initialdelay.in.seconds}000", fixedRateString = "${ingest.rate.in.seconds}000")
    public void ingestData(){
       // Ingestion Logic
    }
}
```

May help you.